# opencart get total price in cart when payment method selected

Tags: php, opencart, payment, cart

This is my custom payment method code for opencart:

```
<?php
class ControllerPaymentportmanat extends Controller {
    protected function index() {
        $this->data['button_confirm'] = $this->language->get('button_confirm_portmanat');

        $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('checkout/success');
        $this->data['order_id'] = $this->session->data['order_id'];

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/portmanat.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/payment/portmanat.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/payment/portmanat.tpl';
        }   

        $this->render();
    }

    public function confirm() {
        $this->load->model('checkout/order');

        $this->model_checkout_order->confirm($this->session->data['order_id'], $this->config->get('portmanat_order_status_id'));
    }
}
?>
```

How can I get current **TOTAL** size on my code? I want to define the **TOTAL** price on my code.

Comment: anyone knows the answer?

Comment: You should be able to pull data via `order_id` somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the order info by using getOrder and using the order_id stored in the session:

```
$order_info = $this->model_checkout_order->getOrder($this->session->data['order_id']);
```

Now you can get the order total by using $order_info['total']